# Splitting array of grouped objects into two evenly

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

So lets say I have an array that looks like this:

```
var addresses = [[{house: "231 Main", id: "someID"},
                  {house: "233 Main", id: "someID"}],
                 [{house: "440 10th Street", id: "someID"},
                  {house: "443 10th Street", id: "someID"},
                  {house: "450 10th Street", id: "someID"}],
                 [{house: "440 11th Street", id: "someID"}]]
```

How could I split this 2d array into two somewhat evenly balanced arrays based on the counts inside the nested arrays? So go from having one array containing three sub array with a total of six items to two arrays each having sub arrays with a total of three items all together.

Comment: You've got one missing brace in that code. Also, have a look at `reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flatten subarrays using `[].concat`, and split it into two subarrays using `slice`

```js
const addresses = [[{house: "231 Main", id: "someID"},
                  {house: "233 Main", id: "someID"}],
                 [{house: "440 10th Street", id: "someID"},
                  {house: "443 10th Street", id: "someID"},
                  {house: "450 10th Street", id: "someID"}],
                 [{house: "440 11th Street", id: "someID"}]]

const flattened = [].concat(...addresses)
const length = flattened.length

const result = [
  flattened.slice(0, Math.floor(length/2)),
  flattened.slice(Math.floor(length/2))
]

console.log(result)
```